# MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE won't start

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench 5.2 CE after start show splash screen and going down.
Operation system - Windows 7.
I think it happens after saving new connection profile.

Answer (score 3):

Helps only deleting all folders and files in

```
C:\Users\..user..\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench
```